# Having problems returning the Total Sum of my Value Field

Tags: arcpy

I am having problems returning the total sum of my value field in my Table after the script has run. Any pointers?

```
import arcpy
import numpy as np
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C:\Users\michellep\Documents\project.gdb'

print "Arcpy & Numpy Successfully Imported"
print "Start Processing"
start = time.time()

sourceFC = 'Test_Group'
sourceFields = ['ID_Data', 'KV', 'AV', 'Total']
pc = r'C:\Users\michellep\Documents\Data\Table.dbf'
PCFields = ['AV', 'KV', 'WV', 'B', 'kW', 'Value']

valueDict = {r[0]:(r[1:]) for r in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sourceFC, sourceFields)}
updateFC = 'Test_Group_update'
updateFields = ['ID_Data', 'KV', 'AV', 'Total']

updateCursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(updateFC, updateFields)
updatePC = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(pc, PCFields)

for UpdateRow in updateCursor:
    keyValue = UpdateRow[0]
    if keyValue in valueDict:
        for row in updatePC:
            row[1] = valueDict[keyValue][1]
            row[0] = valueDict[keyValue][0] 
            row[2] = row[1]/ row[0] * (row[3]/ row[0])
            row[5] = row[2] * row[4]

            arr = arcpy.da.TableToNumPyArray(pc, "Value")
            arr.dtype = np.dtype(float)
            UpdateRow[3] = np.sum(arr)
            updatePC.updateRow(row)
            updateCursor.updateRow(UpdateRow)
            del row
        del UpdateRow

end = time.time()
processTime = end - start
print "Processing Completed - {:.1f} seconds".format(processTime)
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean "having problems"?  That's a bit vague.  Please [edit] your question and clarify exactly what the problem is.